# MySql LIMIT + JOIN is stopping data from being returned?

Tags: mysql

I've got two tables and am trying to return all profiles that are assigned to a specific `cinemaId`.

1. content_content

   - Holds data about `content_profile` (associated

Table:

```
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title                | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slug                 | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| author_id            | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| descr                | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |            |
| layout_type          | varchar(32)  | NO   |     |         |                |             |
| is_feature           | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| main_feature         | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| postcode_id          | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| cinemaId             | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

2. content_profile

   - Holds specific data about a profile (think of a profile as a store with opening ours and etc...)

Table:

```
+------------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| content_ptr_id         | int(11)              | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| body                   | longtext             | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| web_site               | varchar(200)         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| email                  | varchar(75)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |   |
| hours                  | longtext             | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| price_range            | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | |
| primary_category_id    | int(11)              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |   |
+------------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

What I'm trying to do is `select * content_profile where content_content.cinemaId = 2`.

I've built the following query, which joins the two tables together as well as an `content_image` table, this table holds 0-many images for a single `content_profile.content_ptr_id`. Note I've left the `images` table out of this because it doesn't really have anything todo with the question.

```
> select 'profile'.'content_ptr_id' AS
> 'profile.content_ptr_id','profile'.'body' AS
> 'profile.body','profile'.'web_site' AS
> 'profile.web_site','profile'.'email' AS
> 'profile.email','profile'.'hours' AS
> 'profile.hours','profile'.'price_range' AS
> 'profile.price_range','profile'.'price_range_high' AS
> 'profile.show_in_directory','image'.'id' AS
> 'image.id','image'.'content_id' AS 'image.content_id','image'.'type'
> AS 'image.type','image'.'order' AS 'image.order','image'.'caption' AS
> 'image.caption','image'.'author_id' AS
> 'image.author_id','image'.'image' AS 'image.image','image'.'link_url'
> AS 'image.link_url','content'.'id' AS 'content.id','content'.'title'
> AS 'content.title','content'.'slug' AS 'content.slug','content'.'date'
> AS 'content.date','content'.'section' AS
> 'content.section','content'.'author_id' AS
> 'content.author_id','content'.'descr' AS
> 'content.descr','content'.'inline_gallery' AS
> 'content.inline_gallery','content'.'layout_type' AS
> 'content.layout_type','content'.'blog_id' AS
> 'content.main_feature','content'.'miffCinemaId' AS
> 'content.cinemaId'  from (select
> 'content_profile'.'content_ptr_id','content_profile'.'body','content_profile'.'web_site','content_profile'.'email','content_profile'.'hours','content_profile'.'price_range','content_profile'.'price_range_high','content_profile'.'primary_category_id',
> FROM content_profile LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) AS profile  LEFT JOIN
> 'content_content' AS 'content' ON 'profile'.'content_ptr_id' =
> 'content'.'id'  LEFT JOIN 'content_image' AS 'image' ON
> 'profile'.'content_ptr_id' = 'image'.'content_id'  WHERE
> content.cinemaId  =  '2' order by  profile.content_ptr_id ASC,
> content.date DESC
```

I've narrowed my problem down to this line:

```
FROM content_profile LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

For some reason the `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0` is stopping anything from being returned...If I remove these two fields, all the data is returned. Note their are only 3-4 fields with `cinemaId = 2`...So limit 0, 10 should 100% show something right?

### Edit:

If I put the `limit 10 offset 0` at the end of my query, I will only receive the data from 1 profile, depending on how many `content_image`'s are associated to it.

The reason I have the `limit 10 offset 0` inside my `subquery`, is so I get results for the first `10` `content_profile`'s

Answer (score 0):

You have to move  the **LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0** to the end of this query. Because in your query it will limit the return data before you filter data by **WHERE** condition.

```
select 'profile'.'content_ptr_id' AS
'profile.content_ptr_id','profile'.'body' AS
'profile.body','profile'.'web_site' AS
'profile.web_site','profile'.'email' AS
'profile.email','profile'.'hours' AS
'profile.hours','profile'.'price_range' AS
'profile.price_range','profile'.'price_range_high' AS
'profile.show_in_directory','image'.'id' AS
'image.id','image'.'content_id' AS 'image.content_id','image'.'type'
AS 'image.type','image'.'order' AS 'image.order','image'.'caption' AS
'image.caption','image'.'author_id' AS
'image.author_id','image'.'image' AS 'image.image','image'.'link_url'
AS 'image.link_url','content'.'id' AS 'content.id','content'.'title'
AS 'content.title','content'.'slug' AS 'content.slug','content'.'date'
AS 'content.date','content'.'section' AS
'content.section','content'.'author_id' AS
'content.author_id','content'.'descr' AS
'content.descr','content'.'inline_gallery' AS
'content.inline_gallery','content'.'layout_type' AS
'content.layout_type','content'.'blog_id' AS
'content.main_feature','content'.'miffCinemaId' AS
'content.cinemaId'  from (select
'content_profile'.'content_ptr_id','content_profile'.'body','content_profile'.'web_site','content_profile'.'email','content_profile'.'hours','content_profile'.'price_range','content_profile'.'price_range_high','content_profile'.'primary_category_id',
FROM content_profile) AS profile  LEFT JOIN
'content_content' AS 'content' ON 'profile'.'content_ptr_id' =
'content'.'id'  LEFT JOIN 'content_image' AS 'image' ON
'profile'.'content_ptr_id' = 'image'.'content_id'  WHERE
content.cinemaId  =  '2' order by  profile.content_ptr_id ASC,
content.date DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Yep..But if I do this, mysql will return duplicates of the `content_profile` table (difference being the image in each of the content_profile results) up to 10 only, so instead of results for content_id 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9,10 I only get results for content_id 1 (because the content_image table is causing duplicate content_profile results).

Comment: you can use **GROUP BY 'profile'.'content_ptr_id'** to remove duplicates data

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in subquery.

```sql
SELECT
  content_profile.content_ptr_id,
  content_profile.body,
  content_profile.web_site,
  content_profile.email,
  content_profile.hours,
  content_profile.price_range,
  content_profile.price_range_high,
  content_profile.primary_category_id
FROM content_profile
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Look, there is no any `WHERE` clause. This query will return 10 rows from `content_profile` with random `content_ptr_id`. Seems like there are no content for `cinemaId=2` in this 10 rows, and your query in total returns nothing.
@Duc Phan is right: if you need limit, you must put it after query, not in subquery.

But `LIMIT` will never remove duplicates from query. If you don't want to see duplicates, you must use `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`. For example, query can look like this:

```sql
SELECT
  profile.content_ptr_id AS 'profile.content_ptr_id',
  profile.body AS 'profile.body',
  profile.web_site AS 'profile.web_site',
  profile.email AS 'profile.email',
  profile.hours AS 'profile.hours',
  profile.price_range AS 'profile.price_range',
  profile.price_range_high AS 'profile.show_in_directory',
  image.id AS 'image.id',
  image.content_id AS 'image.content_id',
  image.type AS 'image.type',
  image.order AS 'image.order',
  image.caption AS 'image.caption',
  image.author_id AS 'image.author_id',
  image.image AS 'image.image',
  image.link_url AS 'image.link_url',
  content.id AS 'content.id',
  content.title AS 'content.title',
  content.slug AS 'content.slug',
  content.date AS 'content.date',
  content.section AS 'content.section',
  content.author_id AS 'content.author_id',
  content.descr AS 'content.descr',
  content.inline_gallery AS 'content.inline_gallery',
  content.layout_type AS 'content.layout_type',
  content.blog_id AS 'content.main_feature',
  content.miffCinemaId AS 'content.cinemaId'
FROM content_profile AS profile -- no subquery needed, limit moved from here
  JOIN content_content AS content ON profile.content_ptr_id = content.id
  LEFT JOIN content_image AS image ON profile.content_ptr_id = image.content_id
WHERE content.cinemaId = 2
GROUP BY profile.content_ptr_id, content.id -- Remove duplicates with GROUP BY
ORDER BY profile.content_ptr_id ASC,
  content.date DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Notice also, `LEFT JOIN` with `content_content` is replaced with `JOIN`. Because `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE content.cinemaId=2` filter on joined table will act as simple `JOIN`: if there is no matching row in `content_content`, row from `content_profile` will be excluded from resultset.